Php Form With Multiple Submit Buttons - Getting ID of Submit Button That is Clicked - Javascript
I have a php / html form with 4 submit buttons for a POST operation.
The form uses the BootBox modal dialog as a replacement for the vanilla javascript confirm dialog.
I have an issue with javascript and getting the id of the button that
is clicked.
The code for the form is as follows;
  <form  id="pageFormMultiSubmit" action="process.php"  method="post" >

         <!-- several display / input fields -->

         <! -- submit buttons -->

  </form>

The code for the submit buttons are as follows;
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button_submit1" name="viewUser"        
          title="View User" >View Info</button>

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button_submit2" name="editUser"        
          title="Edit User" >Edit Info</button>

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button_submit3" name="delUser"              
          title="Delete User" >Delete Info</button>

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button_submit4" name="resetPwdUser"    
          title="Reset Password" >Reset Passwd</button>

The Javascript code is as follows;
  const formMultiSubmit = document.getElementById('pageFormMultiSubmit');      

  if( formMultiSubmit ){

      let formHandledMS = false;

      formMultiSubmit.addEventListener('submit', event  => {

          let btn = document.getElementById(event.target.id);

          // console.log("Event Target ID : ", event.target.id );

          if( !formHandledMS ) {

              event.preventDefault();

              bootbox.confirm({

                 size: 'small', centerVertical: true,
                 message: 'Proceed With Action?',
                 callback : function(result) {

                     if( result ) {

                         formHandledMS = true;

                         if ( btn ){ 

                              btn.click();
                         }            

                     } else {

                         formHandledMS = false;
                     }
                 }

              }); // end bootbox.confirm

          } // end of if !formHandledMS


      }); //end of formMultiSubmit.addEventListener


  } //end of if formMultiSubmit

console.log("Event Target ID : ", event.target.id ) gives the ID of the form pageFormMultiSubmit
instead of the button that is clicked.
Any idea how I can get the id of the button and proceed
with btn.click() ?
Thanks in advance.

sub to button click()s instead of form submit()s. or add a value to the button and you can see it in php.

Is there a reason for not having an event listener on each btton? It would seem to make it rather easier.

you can sub click on the form and then get the id of the button actually clicked from event.target.

@dandavis - what is the meaning of 'sub click' ?

@AHaworth - Event listener on each button ? U have sample code ?  Pls post an answer.

You may want to add a value attribute to the button. You shouldn't need ids if you already gave them names.

@AHaworth yes, there is a reason: forms can be submitted in many ways, not just by clicking on a button. You should always listen to the submit event.

@Bergi - From above -> The form uses BootBox modal dialog as a replacement for the vanilla javascript confirm dialog. IDs will be needed for Javascript to fire the modal dialog, prevent the default action and then submit the forrm to the processing script.

@MarcoZen No, the ids are not needed, only the references to the button elements - and you can also get those by name. See hedfol's answer below, which doesn't use ids for anything but logging

There is a submitter property containing an element that sent the SubmitEvent.
The button ID can be obtained with event.submitter.id:


document.getElementById('pageFormMultiSubmit').addEventListener('submit', event => {
  const btn = event.submitter;
  if (btn) {
    console.log('Form submitted with button ID: "' + btn.id + '"');
    btn.click();
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log('\t' + event.target.innerText + ' clicked at', Date.now());
}));
<form id="pageFormMultiSubmit">

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button_submit1" name="viewUser" title="View User">View Info</button>

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button_submit2" name="editUser" title="Edit User">Edit Info</button>

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button_submit3" name="delUser" title="Delete User">Delete Info</button>

  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button_submit4" name="resetPwdUser" title="Reset Password">Reset Passwd</button>

</form>




Thanks. I changed let btn = document.getElementById(event.target.id); to let btn = document.getElementById(event.submitter.id)  in my code.

I've updated an answer to express that more explicitly. Thanks!
